# PHP how to get size of all files in one directory?

Tags: php

I want to get size of all files in one directory.Here is code that i have tried

```
$files=scandir(__DIR__,1);
echo $files[0]["size"];
```

This code saves all files in `$files` but it saves only its' names not sizes.

Comment: There's no built-in for this, you'd have to recursively iterate over the files and sum up each one's size. You're probably better off using a shell command like `du`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky how can i iterate through all files in PHP?

Comment: What is the desired result? One number - the total size of all files in the directory or an array (key = filename, value = size)? What about subdirectories?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil yes just one number the total size.There are no subdirecotires.

Comment: See [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator `](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: If you're certain you never need to worry about subdirs, you can use [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
function getDirSize($path)
{
    $fio = popen('/usr/bin/du -sb '.$path, 'r');
    $size = intval(fgets($fio,80));
    pclose($fio);
    return $size;
}
```

or

```
function getDirSize($path) {
    $size = 0;
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file){
        $size+=$file->getSize();
    }
    return $size;
}
```